# Geolocation gets old coordinates

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic4

I'm following this [vlog](https://medium.com/@rajeshpriyadarshinimishra/location-permissions-and-accuracy-ionic-4-cdc9729485b5) on getting accurate current location (I used the final approach)

here's a snippet of what I've tried so far to get the current location:

```
async getLocationCoordinates() {
  const options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    maximumAge: 60000
 };
  return new Promise<LocationResult>((resolve, reject) => {
     this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {
     this.coordinates.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
     this.coordinates.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
     this.coordinates.accuracy = resp.coords.accuracy;
     console.log(resp, 'get locc');
     resolve(this.coordinates);
  }).catch((error) => {
     alert('Error getting location');
     reject(false);
   });
  });
```

When I first tried this out. My accuracy was 100 but when I tried it on another location it's giving me the previous coordinates (when I tried it the first time) and the accuracy went down to 17.

The phone I'm using is Samsung. Any suggestions how I can improve the accuracy? Or should I use another package.

I also checked my google maps if there's anything wrong with my GPS but it's showing me the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your **maximumAge** Variable!

maximumAge: Accept a cached position whose age is no greater than the specified time in milliseconds. (Number)

**For Samsung Devices** Also check your smartphone position settings:

https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/improve-location-accuracy/

Comment: added it because saw someone suggest to add the options variable in the `getCurrentPosition` method to improve accuracy. I removed it as you suggested but it's still the same :(

Comment: Did you tried to change your device? Which Samsung are you using?

Comment: I've edited my answer, follow Samsung tuts form mobile position settings